# I need help to integrate OpenStreetMap with Android

Tags: android, openstreetmap

Good Morning,

Part of my question uses the word OpenStreetMap instead of osmdroid because part of what I need is a map visual reference/preference for users of my app but I need a grid reference of a map not just lat/long.  I believe it was a link from SO that lead me to this: http://dhost.info/usngweb/USNG_OL.html.  This is very much what I had in mind for the visual side of my app.  The grid is right there.  In other words part of what I need has already been created.

The author of the grid in above link uses JavaScript to create the grid of the Military Grid Reference System, which I am familiar with from IBM's tutorial - and zip j-coordconvert.

My question:

1.) In the above link there are radio buttons to switch from the type of map and also the meter zoom.  Would it be good advice to use an Action Bar to allow user's to adjust these preference's?  Has this also already been done?

2.) If the advice is to use an Action Bar - once user has selected a preference he/she will go to another choice with the original selection seldom changing - would I build that Action Bar up so that I have http interface with the above OpenStreetMap?  If your advice was not to re-invent the wheel and use http to reference the already created grid, I would want to grab user's preference is there a code snippet to get the selected preference from http into Sqllite?

This last question my end up being the biggest part of this set off questions - getting the zoom level from http into Sqllite.

Of note:

-Will, at first only be needing one rather big city in U.S. so can cut tiles needed down

-Need rather quick solution on map side as other parts of app will take longer, so can build up my own map grid over time

-Could cut out the selecting of different map types but not grid zoom

-Using latest version of Android Studio

-Familiar with retrofit

-Referencing Busy Coder's Guide 6.6

-Would prefer to stay in Java rather than JavaScript

-Will be targeting newer phones/Android version above 3

I know this is a lot to ask but I am rather new to Android and my head is swimming with the amount of information out there (a good thing).

Thanks,
Terry

Comment: Please just ask a single question at a time.

Comment: Sure. Is there code snippet or link to advise on getting a preference from a map source to sqlite?

Comment: I would recommend that you write a new question where you focus on your specific problem. For example, I have no idea what "getting a preference from a map source to sqlite" means.

Comment: I can see that you are right. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "preference from map source to sqlite".

If you need to provide a TOC (that selector on top right) you need to build up your UI and do the logic for enabling/changing layers (what you see on the map).

You can use Google Maps API (v2) to have the map (just set the map type to NONE and add openstreetmap as a TileProvider, there's a lot of examples, just google it).
For the grid, a brief look at the page source code seems that the grid is created by javascript and is not a webservice that provides tiles (isn't it?). If so you have to create your logic that creates the tiles given the coordinates, this is a bit long to do, but you could look at some code online, for example Google I/O app has something with SVG files:
https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fsamples%2Fapps%2Fiosched%2Fui%2FSVGTileProvider.java

About preferences on enabled layers you can use SharedPreferences.

Comment: I will work up logic and if needed start new question.  However your answer gives a lead or two.  Thank you.

Comment: Ok, if you want you can accept the answer or later on ask again. If you do a new question just ping me on that, I'm not very active on research and could pass weeks before finding it.
Happy you had some good help ;)